# rails aasm: Get all states that allow an specific event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I'm new to AASM, and trying to get a list of all states in a MyModel model that can transition to state :newstate.

So, for example:

```
  aasm_event :finish do
    transitions :to => :finalstate, :from => [:start, :working]
  end
```

Basically, I want to return the [:start, :working] array via the model, so something along the lines of

```
MyModel.aasm_events.finish.transitions.from
```

But, well, that's not the syntax...and I can't find anything for it in the docs.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't supported until now. Freshly released **gem version 3.0.12** now supports a class method called **aasm_from_states_for_state** which does exactly what you asked for. Unfortunately, your suggested little DSL (...finish.transitions.from) is very nice, but not available for now. But I will keep it in mind ;)

Use the new class method like this:

```
MyModel.aasm_from_states_for_state(:finalstate)
```

which returns all possible from states. If you want only the from states for a specific transition:

```
MyModel.aasm_from_states_for_state(:finalstate, :transition => :finish)
```

or more modern (using Ruby 1.9)

```
MyModel.aasm_from_states_for_state(:finalstate, transition: :finish)
```

All calls return an array of possible from states.

Comment: just a hint: the source code indicates, that the method `aasm_from_states_for_state` will be removed in version 4.x
-> ".aasm_from_states_for_state is deprecated and will be removed in version 4.0.0; please use .aasm.from_states_for_state instead!"